# Airflow: Issues with Calling TaskGroup

Tags: airflow

I am having issues with calling TaskGroups, the error log thinks my Job id is `avg_speed_20220502_22c11bdf` instead of just `avg_speed`, and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
with DAG(
        'debug_bigquery_data_analytics',
         catchup=False,
         default_args=default_arguments) as dag:

    # Note to self: the bucket region and the dataproc cluster should be in the same region
    create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id='create_cluster',
        ...
    )

    with TaskGroup(group_id='weekday_analytics') as weekday_analytics:
        avg_temperature = DummyOperator(task_id='avg_temperature')

        avg_tire_pressure = DummyOperator(task_id='avg_tire_pressure')

        avg_speed = DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator(
            task_id='avg_speed',
            project_id='...',
            main=f'gs://.../.../avg_speed.py',
            cluster_name=f'spark-cluster-{{ ds_nodash }}',
            region='...',
            dataproc_jars=['gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar'],
        )

        avg_temperature >> avg_tire_pressure >> avg_speed

    delete_cluster = DataprocDeleteClusterOperator(
        task_id='delete_cluster',
        project_id='...',
        cluster_name='spark-cluster-{{ ds_nodash }}',
        region='...',
        trigger_rule='all_done',
    )

create_cluster >> weekday_analytics >> delete_cluster
```

Here's the error message I get:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Job id 'weekday_analytics.avg_speed_20220502_22c11bdf' must conform to '[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{0,98}[a-zA-Z0-9])?' pattern
[2022-05-02, 11:46:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1278} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=debug_bigquery_data_analytics, task_id=weekday_analytics.avg_speed, execution_date=20220502T184410, start_date=20220502T184610, end_date=20220502T184611
[2022-05-02, 11:46:11 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:93} ERROR - Failed to execute job 549 for task weekday_analytics.avg_speed (400 Job id 'weekday_analytics.avg_speed_20220502_22c11bdf' must conform to '[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{0,98}[a-zA-Z0-9])?' pattern; 18116)
[2022-05-02, 11:46:11 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-05-02, 11:46:11 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Airflow task identifier is `task_id`. However when using TaskGroups you can have same `task_id` in different groups thus tasks defined in task group have identifier of `group_id.task_id`.

For [`apache-airflow-providers-google>7.0.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/):

The [bug](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/23439) has been fixed. It should work now.

For [`apache-airflow-providers-google<=7.0.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/):

You are having issues because [`DataprocJobBaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/05ccfd42f28db7d0a8fe3ed023b0e7a8ec188609/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L836-L838) has:

> ```
> :param job_name: The job name used in the DataProc cluster. This name by default
>     is the task_id appended with the execution data, but can be templated. The
>     name will always be appended with a random number to avoid name clashes.
> ```

The problem is that Airflow adds the `.` char and Google doesn't accept it thus to fix your issue you must override the default of `job_name` parameter to a string of your choice. You can set it to be the `task_id` if you wish.

I opened https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/23439 to report this bug in the meantime you can follow the suggestion above.